# Boil water inside a small container with an arduino

Tags: arduino-uno

I am currently working with a sciene/electronic project where i need "steam". In order to create steam i need to boil water and i plan to boil it inside a very small container [around 5cmx5cmx5cm]. What i want to do is to control this with an arduino but I am very unsure on what step i currently need to make. Are there any "heating-up" modules out there? Or would I need to order a mini-mini kettle and connect that to my arduino?

I am very grateful for every advice i can get because as u can tell i am a bit confused as of right now!

Comment: You need a little pot and a flame.  Or some small electric heater.  What role will the Arduino play in all of this?

Comment: @Delta_G Ok. It will be the one controlling when the heating should start and also im getting a module that will monitor the temperature

Comment: So there is for example not a "heating plate" module that u can connect to an arduino that u know of? @Delta_G

Comment: Just use a thermocoupler. No need for an arduino here.

Comment: I you only want the steam/smoke effect, I'd suggest using ultrasonic air humidifier ([like this one](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00GSKCW70/)). [Example usage](https://learn.adafruit.com/glowing-smokey-skull/overview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to find a boiler pot on electricity (I doubt you can heat water to boiling temperature with like 5V (unless you use many amperes).

Use a relais to switch it on with an Arduino.

Use a temperature sensor (0-150 degrees or so) to decide when to switch it off.

Warning: Get first some electrical knowledge before you start with >200 volts projects since it can be deadly. And boiling water can be devestating for skin and your Arduino.

Comment: Okok. I see there are some heating pads out there that u can connect straight to an arduino but they seem to only reach a deegre of 40 degrees. I might put this project to rest since my electrical knowledge aint that high and i dont plan to die anytime soon! Thx a ton for ur answer

Comment: Good luck ... Probably 40 degrees is what can be maximaly achieved by regular/normal 5V adapters, especially those from Arduino. It's always best to give such 'high power' devices separate power as from the Arduino.

Comment: https://www.banggood.com/Waterproof-Silicone-Flexible-Heating-Pad-6060MM-DC-12V-10W-p-972464.html That product looks pretty interesting

Comment: You can try, but even for this you need a relais, so the answer will still be similar (except for the electricy / high power warning).